# Line 0: Parsing error: Invalid array length in react app

Tags: reactjs, jsx, babeljs

Using VScode I followed Mosh tutorial on youtube: https://youtu.be/Ke90Tje7VS0?t=1080

The first code is to write in index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const element = </h1>Hello World</h1>;
```

and it's already giving me error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
  Line 0:  Parsing error: Invalid array length
```

It's caused by `const element = </h1>Hello World</h1>;` line.

If I put quotes like this `const element = '</h1>Hello World</h1>';`
then it compiles.

What could be the case?

EDIT:
I didn't notice I used closing  tag at the beginning.

Comment: It should be `const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;` (The closing tag `</h1>` at the begging might be causing issue)

Comment: yes you are right. I didnt see that at all. Why dont u answer so i can give you checkmark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a typo, It should be a valid `JSX` tag (The closing tag `</h1>` at the begging might be causing issue)

```
const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSX tags must be opened and closed, as HTML tags.

You have two closing tags. (`</h1>`)

Try:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const element = <h1>Hello World</h1>;
```

Answer (score 1):

React uses JSX, or TSX
to blend UI with logic.

JSX esentially combine HTML with javascript logic in the same location.

The element has a closing tag in the wrong postion

```
const element = <h1>Hello, world!</h1>;
```

If you assign element to `'<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'` it will just create a javascript constant with the string value.